# Where is the Configuration File saved in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, settings

### Issue:

- Applies to: .Net core 3.1 WPF Gui application

in a .net core application, I cannot find the configuration file.
It must have been created somewhere since the application can load and store settings correctly.

Anyone an idea where the file might have been saved?

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create .net core wpf gui app
2. Create a `Settings File`:
   [image]
3. Write stuff to configuration:

```
config.Default.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
config.Default.Save();
config.Default.Reload();
```

4. Relaunch the application and make sure that stuff is loaded correctly from the configuration:
   [image]
5. According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and to Experience from previous .Net 4.5 Apps, a `config.xml` file should be created in the application's directory. But there is nothing to be found:
   [image]

Also a Search in the whole project directory yields no result:
[image]

Comment: What's `config.Default.FilePath`?

Comment: CS1061 'config' does not contain a definition for 'FilePath' and no accessible extension Method 'FilePath'...

Comment: Sorry, I confused Configuration and Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings files are now saved under the following path:

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\[Your_App_Name]\[Your_App_Name]_Url_yhk4xacfqpnpuvqwry4zvrqsrky5rxpk\[Version]`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a file in a wrong directory. I've followed steps and created *.settings file. It's located in same folder along with *.csproj file.

You've mentioned config.xml file. Guess, now it's a part of a *.settings file. Try to open a *.settings file with some code editor like VS Code and you will see an xml inside of it. I guess that's what you're looking for.

Comment: The settings file you mentioned is the preset file Visual Studio uses to Build the application. It does not contain the Currently stored Configuration but only the Default settings: `<Setting Name="LastUpdate" Type="System.DateTime" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">2020-10-04</Value>` - Notice the 'LastUpdate' Date is in the past here and does not contain time information